# Why does my system get stuck at the splash screen after updating to Gnome 3?

Tags: 11.04, boot, upgrade, gnome

Im a newbie to Linux and today I installed gnome-shell and I had previously installed nvidea current drivers provided by Ubuntu. After reboot it shows ubuntu splash screen and then stays there and doesn't do anything. I then went in CLI mode using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and from there I ran command `startx`. Then it loads and then crashes and shows a message saying some error has occured and gives a logout button. I tried

`dpkg-reconfigure Xserver-xorg`

but nothing has happened. Can anyone please give me solution for this?

Comment: Please file a bug by running `ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg` from the terminal.